# Can I send a message to a device (instead of browser) in firebase?

Tags: firebase

I'm using firebase in javascript. It works fine for sending messages to a user while the browser is open, using the id from messaging.getToken. Obviously, the user stops getting these messages if they close the browser tab. Is it at all possible (without creating a separate app) to send these messages to a device after the browser has closed?

Answer (score 0):

That is possible, servicer workers to the rescue! Service workers will allow you to send the user push notifications even after the browser tab is closed. The firebase documentation has a section on this  [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client)

Comment: It's weird, I'm using almost that exact sample code and it doesn't send the messages with the browser closed unless the subsriber token is from IE edge (in which case it shows one of those windows notifications)

Comment: Service workers in IE are only supported from version 17 onwards. See support [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=serviceworkers)

Comment: I'd expect it to work from chrome though (on an android device) and it does work with the browser open but not closed.

Comment: Can you edit your post with the code you have tried?

Comment: I'm using the sample messaging code found at https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging